# Laravel 5: Can't get id when using GET method with model binding

Tags: php, forms, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I need to use GET in my form in order to generate a url query string, but I also need the model id to use in my route. Basically, I want to extend the show($id) method with a url query string generated by the form submission. But it's not getting the id. (The POST method isn't getting it either.)

Here's what I have:

fund.blade.php

```
{!! Form::model($fund, ['route' => 'funds.getQuery', 'method' => 'get'], $fund->id) !!}
{!! Form::select('from', $years) !!}
{!! Form::select('to', $years) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Submit') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('funds/test/{funds}', [ 'as' => 'funds.getQuery', function($id){

$to = Input::get('to');

$from = Input::get('from');

$donations = Donation::whereBetween('Date_Submitted_Adjusted', [
                new Carbon($to),
                new Carbon($from)
             ])
            ->orderBy('Date_Submitted_Adjusted', 'asc')
            ->get();

$urlString = url('funds', $parameters = [
    'id' => $id,
    'from' => $from,
    'to' => $to
]);

return $urlString;

}]);
```

My show/{id} method is working fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In looking at some online documentation, it appears the specific object id should be passed along with the route. Instead of this:

{!! Form::model($fund, ['route' => 'funds.getQuery', 'method' => 'get'], $fund->id) !!}

Can you try the following?

{!! Form::model($fund, ['route' => array('funds.getQuery', $fund->id), 'method' => 'get']) !!}